# Portable library in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am new to .net core and having doubt about portable libraries.

I have created .net core web application, and framework section of project.json looks as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
"imports": [
"portable-net4+netcore45"
],
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"type": "platform"
}
}
}
}
```

Now in above case, what is meaning of "portable-net4+netcore45"?

Does it mean, that I can run my .net core application on machine where only .net framework 4 is installed?

Will it work without .net core installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the above will still require .NET Core to be installed, because you are using `"type": "platform"`, which requires a platform to be installed and the package itself serves only as reference.

If you want to run w/o .NET Core framework/SDK being installed, you have to change it to

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
},
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64": {}
}
```

Please note that the "runtimes" section is added, this is **required** if you want to run w/o installing a .NET Core runtime and you need to add any target OS to this list, like Linux etc.

The `"imports": ["portable-net4+netcore45"]` section only tells NuGet that it should install portable libraries which match the two targets, even if they do not support `netcoreapp1.0`/`netstandard1.6` yet.

Most libraries which target Win8/8.1/UWP should work, but there is no guarantee. Import just tells nuget "install it anyways".

Check out the MSDN Docs on how to target the different [.NET Core App Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types).